# How to get A Specifc Key => value pair from an assosative array in Php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array

**Given Data**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => /w/s/wsh11-blue_main.jpg
            [image_id] => L3cvcy93c2gxMS1ibHVlX21haW4uanBn
            [file_path] => /w/s/wsh11-blue_main.jpg
            [file_name] => wsh11-blue_main.jpg
            [added_at] => September 19 2019 09:32:24
            [serial_no] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => /w/s/wsh05-purple_main.jpg
            [image_id] => L3cvcy93c2gwNS1wdXJwbGVfbWFpbi5qcGc,
            [file_path] => /w/s/wsh05-purple_main.jpg
            [file_name] => wsh05-purple_main.jpg
            [added_at] => September 19 2019 09:32:24
            [serial_no] => 2
        }

}
```

Now my problem is want to get a specific column in another array

i have tried `array_column($data,'file_path')` but unfortunate i am getting value only not key

i want to get An Expect Array Like

**Expected Result**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file_path] => /w/s/wsh11-blue_main.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file_path] => /w/s/wsh05-purple_main.jpg
            )

    }
```

Comment: i want to convert this array to CSV in magneto iam getting error in simple  Array

Comment: And what's the problem with `for` loop?

Comment: i have to pass only single array to a funtion, i cant call that function recusilvily..

Comment: Iterate over first array with `for` or `foreach` and build required array. There's nothing about recursion here.

Comment: >>> i have to pass only single array to a funtion, i cant call that function recusilvily. Can you elaborate it with your code you have done till now?@WaqarAli

Comment: @WaqarAli the function you are talking about, for it, you may declare a global variable or a member variable in class. Play around the variable to get the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

```
$arrayRec= array ();

foreach ($arrayRec as $rec){
   $collection[] = array('file_path'=>$rec['file_path']);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: you will get the result that like you expect

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a loop to build a new array with the expected data. An alternative is the `array_map()` function. It iterates over each array element and collects the return values into a new array.

```
$data = [
    [
        'image_id' => 'L3cvcy93c2gxMS1ibHVlX21haW4uanBn',
        'file_path' => '/w/s/wsh11-blue_main.jpg'
    ],
    [
        'image_id' => 'L3cvcy93c2gwNS1wdXJwbGVfbWFpbi5qcGc',
        'file_path' => '/w/s/wsh05-purple_main.jpg'
    ]
];

$mapped = array_map(
    static function ($file) {
      return ['file_path' => $file['file_path']];   
    },
    $data
);

var_dump($mapped);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["file_path"]=>
    string(24) "/w/s/wsh11-blue_main.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["file_path"]=>
    string(26) "/w/s/wsh05-purple_main.jpg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$newArray = array();
$arr = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if($key == "file_path"){
        $arr[$key] = $value;
        $newArray[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array, get the value from the inner array and save it in the new array.

```
$finalArray = [];
for($finalData as $innerArray){
            $finalArray[] = array('file_path'=>$innerArray['innerArray']);
}
```

`$finalArray` has what you need.